# Where in India can I find a synagogue

Tags: synagogue

ભારતમાં ક્યાં હું એક સભાસ્થાનમાં શોધી શકો છો
Where in India can I find a synagogue

શાંતિ

Comment: Try http://www.chabad.org/centers/default_cdo/country/India/jewish/Chabad-Lubavitch.htm

Comment: @Double AA Chabad વેબસાઇટ ગુજરાતી વેબપેજ હોય ​​છે

Answer (score 5):

[Synagogues in India](http://www.mavensearch.com/synagogues/C3396) gives a list of the current synagogues in India. Not all of them show services. Some of them are

Chabad Lubavitch - Mumbai, India [view street map](http://www.mavensearch.com/synagogues/map/7992)  [Website](http://www.chabad.org/centers/default_cdo/aid/118651/jewish/Chabad-Lubavitch-of-Mumbai.htm)
Nariman House, 5, Hormusji street,
colaba
Bombay 400-005  Chabad Lubavitch
Tel: 91-222-283-6921
Fri Evening Services   Shabbat Morning Services   High Holidays   Tourist Visits

Etz Chaim Prayer Hall [view street map](http://www.mavensearch.com/synagogues/map/7376)
Balu Changu Patil Marg
Umerkhadi
Bombay  Sephardi

Beth El Synagogue [view street map](http://www.mavensearch.com/synagogues/map/6782)
909 Mahatma Gandhi Rd
Panvel
Marharashtra    Orthodox
Tel: 91 22-745-1014
Daily Services   Fri Evening Services   Shabbat Morning Services   High Holidays   Tourist Visits

Ohel David Synagogue [view street map](http://www.mavensearch.com/synagogues/map/7349)
9, Dr. Ambedkar Road
Pune
Marharashtra 411 001    Orthodox
Tel: 091 20 6132048

See the link for others